# gMaps Markers and InfoWindow with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) to implement the map on my Angular page and following [this example](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!custom-marker-ng-repeat.html) (linked by the README file on ng-map GitHub rep).

My purpose is to have multiple markers (using ng-repeat) and one InfoWindow to expose some releated information. For semplicity the model I use is a Lawyer. So the markers will represents the lawyer positions and the infoWindow will expose their info.

With that in mind, this is the code of my template (simplified):

```
<div>
  <ng-map default-style="true">

    <marker ng-repeat="lawyer in vm.data.lawyers track by $index" id="marker-{{$index}}" position="{{lawyer.address}}" on-click="vm.map.showInfoWindow('foo', 'marker-'+$index);"></marker> 

    <info-window id="foo" on-mouseover=vm.mouseover()>
      <div class="customWindow" ng-non-bindable="">
        My name is {{lawyer.firstname}}, etc...
      </div>
    </info-window>

  </ng-map>
</div>
```

My (also simplified) Controller istead is:

```
myCtrl(NgMap, authentication){
  var vm = this;

  //Getting the map instance
  NgMap
    .getMap()
    .then(function(map) {
      vm.map = map;
    });

   //Getting Data (lawyer and cabinet)
        authentication.lawyersAll()
            .success(function(data){
                vm.data = { lawyers: data }                    
            })
            .error(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });

}
```

How I can bind the markers and the infoWindow?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

Is that possible using a custom behaviour on the click of the marker: once clicked, save the model to the controller and load the model data from the InfoWindow. Pretty straightforward.

Example here: https://ngmap.github.io/#/!infowindow_ng_click.html with Pluncker associated inside it.